# pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi doesn't compile under v0.9.35

Tags: runtime

I have a template node with some offchain worker code that builds well with v0.9.28 dependencies.
The runtime also implements pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi trait.

Now I'm trying to upgrade dependencies to v0.9.35 and, after necessary code changes I managed to build it, but only if I comment out pallet_contracts_rpc_runtime_api::ContractsApi implementation.

However when I try to include it I get the following error:

```
 error[E0152]: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `sp_application_crypto` depends on): `panic_impl`.
|
= note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
= note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/yury/Desktop/SpiderWeb/FirstReceivedFromLucas/failed_upgrade_mvp-full-node-without-github-files/spiderweb-chain/target/release/wbuild/spiderweb-substrate-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-830f6a13a9ed9382.rmeta
= note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/yury/Desktop/SpiderWeb/FirstReceivedFromLucas/failed_upgrade_mvp-full-node-without-github-files/spiderweb-chain/target/release/wbuild/spiderweb-substrate-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-6baa34cc3788d70b.rmeta
```

In both cases (success and failure) running

```
cargo tree -i sp-io
```

yields the same result:

```
error: There are multiple `sp-io` packages in your project, and the specification `sp-io` is ambiguous.
```

Please re-run this command with `-p <spec>` where `<spec>` is one of the following:
sp-io@6.0.0
sp-io@7.0.0

In my Cargo.toml file all relevant dependencies refer to v7.0.0

Now I saw posts with similar though not exactly the same issues and suspect there is some std code leaked in the Runtime, or maybe I do something incorrect here ?